# how to modify the text of the alert view which is shown when i have finished jumped to other application

Tags: ios

Now I saw a alert view as shown below.
How to modify the text which tells me to choose the action.
[the text which is end with X is what I want to modify.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITLW5.jpg)
thanks.

Comment: just look at your code. check if you are setting alertview with that title of button

Comment: Have solved this problem. I thought it may be a system alert view which I can't modify when I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like an alert box. Alerts are usually called as

```
alert(text);
```

where text is what that will be displayed in the popup followed by an OK.

Answer (score 0):

Create an alert view and add title, message and text of buttons to be shown. For example:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Other", nil];
[alertView show];
```